# I want a cell to change colour on 15 characters in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I want to use a formula to change the colour of a cell if it is >= 15 characters in Excel 2010.  I have tried the below but it did not work - does anyone have any ideas.

len(a1)>=15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step by step:

- Select the cell
- Go to `Home` tab
- From `Conditional Formatting` choose `Highlight Cell Rules` > `More Rules`
- Select `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`
- Write `=LEN($A1)>=15` as formula and select format (change colors etc.)